# DOMException: "Invalid header name."

Tags: header, powerbi, report, embedding

I've got this error "DOMException: "Invalid header name."

while embedding a power bi Report in my Wordpress site.. after that it turns out that "This content isn't available."  I've checked the group ID and the report ID multiple times

But nothing going smooth ... how this supposed to be solved?

Comment: are you able to reach your report via postman or web (rest api)/ do you have access to the report?

Comment: Yes I can through the Power BI Embedded Playground here https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html

but actually it fails using this plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/embed-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when tried to put too long String into a header.
Solved by using Request Body instead.